# Keras & R: cropping center of layer output

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use the U-Net architecture for an image segmentation task. To reduce edge effects, I thought about using U-Net without zero-padding, same as the creators of U-Net did. But everywhere I looked, I did not find an implementation of U-Net without padding. There is even a package called "unet" in R ([link to the package on github](https://github.com/r-tensorflow/unet/blob/master/R/model.R)), but it does not allow for `padding = "valid"`. I guess the reason is the resulting necessity to "crop" the images before the concatenation ([as can be seen in this picture](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/)). How could I implement this in Keras with R? I am still a newbie to Keras and R and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You could try creating your own copy of the unet repository and modify it. For example, modify the model.R file to change the padding variable from "same" to "valid".

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano I know, but my problem is how to implement the "crop" step, where I crop the output feature map of one layer to fit the other layer, in order to concatenate them. I don't know how to do that.